# Need help to install Graphviz in databricks

Tags: databricks, graphviz

Working on generating a report using databricks. The package I used need to install Graphviz to access full visualization capabilities.

How to install Graphviz in my system?

I have tried to pip install Graphviz, but it did not work.

[databricks can't display graph directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwr1d.png)

Comment: Did the pip install complete successfully? Please note that if you pip install in a notebook, when you restart the cluster you need to install again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install graphviz Linux package. There are two variants:

1. Install it in the notebook directly using the shell commands:

```
%sh apt-get update; apt-get -f -y install graphviz
```

2. Install it using an [init script](https://docs.databricks.com/en/init-scripts/cluster-scoped.html) that will do the same as in notebook, but automatically on cluster start. Create a file in the workspace with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get -f -y install graphviz
```

and attach it to the cluster.